# Raisin awareness: need to squash [grape], which jams together unrelated flavors: Groovy and Ruby

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) tag is currently used for two completely different technologies: the Groovy [Grape](http://groovy-lang.org/grape.html) dependency manager and the Ruby [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) API framework.

The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/grape/info) clearly states this split is intended:

> [Grape](http://groovy-lang.org/grape.html) (The Groovy Adaptable Packaging Engine or Groovy Advanced Packaging Engine) is the infrastructure enabling the grab() calls in Groovy, a set of classes leveraging Ivy to allow for a repository driven module system for Groovy. This allows a developer to write a script with an essentially arbitrary library requirement, and ship just the script. Grape will, at runtime, download as needed and link the named libraries and all dependencies.
>
> [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) (The Ruby REST micro-framework) is a framework that allows for quickly defining REST-like interfaces. It provides a DSL for defining versioned APIs as a collection of entities mounted on Rack.

However, my observation on Stack Overflow is that each tag should be distinct, and not refer to multiple unrelated concepts.  This split usage therefore seems at odds with the intended use of tags.

Looking at the tag usage history, it looks like the tag was originally used for Groovy Grape starting in 2008.  The first Ruby question was added in 2011.  The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5461640/revisions) first referenced Groovy Grape in 2011, and then was updated to reference Ruby Grape in 2013.

### Usage

Currently, there are 447 questions tagged with [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape).  Of these, 73 are also tagged with [groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy).  199 are tagged with [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), and 128 are tagged with [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) but not [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby).

There also exists a [grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api) tag with 313 questions, 197 of which don't also have [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape).  This tag [also refers to](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/grape-api/info) the Ruby version of [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape), and so is a synonym of it:

> [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape#readme) is a REST-like API micro-framework for Ruby. It’s designed to run on Rack or complement existing web application frameworks such as Rails and Sinatra by providing a simple DSL to easily develop RESTful APIs.

The [groovy-grab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grab) tag has only 3 questions, and refers to [`@Grab`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Grab.html), the main annotation used by Groovy Grape.

### What to do?

It seems clear that [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) as it currently exists should be squashed, though the question is what to do about it.  Hence this question raisin awareness of the current jam.

It feels like this tag should be split into two different tags.  I'm not sure whether the existing [grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api) is a sufficiently well named tag for the Ruby half, but it at least already unambiguously refers to the Ruby API.  [groovy-grab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grab) is barely used, but it too is unambiguous, and refers to the Groovy Grape.

Does it make the most sense to have [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape) and [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape)?  Or maybe [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape) and [grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api)?  Either way, it seems clear the existing [grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api) & [groovy-grab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grab) tags should be rolled into whatever the split is.

Comment: If there were a "best-of-Meta" list, I would nominate this to be on it. You truly got it ripe. Although there'll be a bunch of work to do, and even some who wine, your efforts in raisin this currant issue will not be fruitless. We are grapeful for your help.

Comment: This is just sour grapes.

Comment: I think the two proposed tags — [tag:groovy-grape] and [tag:ruby-grape] — make a lot of sense.  With those in place, I suspect that both [tag:groovy-api] and [tag:groovy-grab] could be made synonyms of [tag:groovy-grape].  Or, perhaps, the [tag:groovy-grab] questions could simply be retagged and the tag left to wither and die naturally (3 questions won't tax anyone's editing).  I fully support a proposal along these lines (even though I know barely anything of the products in question).

Comment: This post is a sticky spread of dad jokes and I love it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I created an answer more-or-less along these lines, to see what the community consensus is based on the voting patterns: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417346/1108305

Comment: Making Wine Is Fine

Comment: Enough with the purple prose.

Comment: @matt I'm not 100% sure if that's meant seriously (i.e. stop with the puns and references), as a reference itself (since grapes are often purple), or both…

Comment: Just trying to promote Concord.

Comment: I'm crushed....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At this point, I'm leaning toward us creating two new tags: [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape) and [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape).  The existing [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) questions would be retagged as one or the other of these (or untagged if there are any questions related to neither).  The [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) tag would be left without any remaining questions and be left to wither and die on the vine.

[grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api) would become a synonym of [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape).  We can probably get rid of [groovy-grab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grab) after changing its three questions to [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape), though leaving it as a synonym for [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape) might make sense despite the low number of questions as it'd be a good signpost for people who don't know that the built-in `@Grab` annotation is part of a technology called "Grape".

Answer (score 10):

If we are going with the two tag idea, the cleanest way to tackle it would be to manually retag the 73 [[groovy] + [grape]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgrape%5D+%5Bgroovy%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) questions to [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape) first. (Also note that if you see any post that needs attention, like editing or closure, do make sure that you do so before replacing the tag)

After this, a moderator can rename the tag from [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) to [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape). In this way, we would not be bumping all the 400+ questions that are tagged with [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape).

We would also need to go through the 32 Questions [`[grape] -[ruby] -[ruby-on-rails] -[grape-api] -[groovy] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgrape%5D+-%5Bruby%5D+-%5Bruby-on-rails%5D+-%5Bgrape-api%5D+-%5Bgroovy%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) (you can narrow this down too!) manually and attach one of the required tags.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was wondering what the actual retagging process would look like.  I can start looking at retagging the Groovy ones starting later this evening.

Comment: I've manually retagged the Groovy grape questions to [tag:groovy-grape].  I'm waiting for a tag wiki to be approved for that new tag.  I've put in a request for a moderator to rename [tag:grape] to [tag:ruby-grape]: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417461/1108305.  I've put in a tag wiki change request for the existing [grape] tag to drop the references to Groovy Grape.

Comment: You don't need to post a new question for that. You can either ping a moderator in chat, or raise a flag on this post to get their attention. I would wait a few days to see if any mod automatically notices this post first.

Comment: I've been on Stack Overflow for 10 years, and I've never used chat, so that didn't even occur to me as the appropriate option.