# Please rename tag [grape] to [ruby-grape] and make [grape-api] a synonym for [ruby-grape]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The consensus from [Raisin awareness: need to squash [grape], which jams together unrelated flavors: Groovy and Ruby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417325/1108305) appears to be that the existing [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) tag be split into [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape) and [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape).  Additionally, the [grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api) tag should be made a synonym of [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape), as it is another tag referring to the same thing.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417380/1108305) suggested approaching this by manually retagging the Groovy questions as [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape), and then having a moderator rename the remaining 367 [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) questions to [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape).

> If we are going with the two tag idea, the cleanest way to tackle it would be to manually retag the 73 [[groovy] + [grape]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgrape%5D+%5Bgroovy%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) questions to [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape) first. (Also note that if you see any post that needs attention, like editing or closure, do make sure that you do so before replacing the tag)
>
> After this, a moderator can rename the tag from [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) to [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape). In this way, we would not be bumping all the 400+ questions that are tagged with [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape).
>
> We would also need to go through the 32 Questions [`[grape] -[ruby] -[ruby-on-rails] -[grape-api] -[groovy] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgrape%5D+-%5Bruby%5D+-%5Bruby-on-rails%5D+-%5Bgrape-api%5D+-%5Bgroovy%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) (you can narrow this down too!) manually and attach one of the required tags.

I have gone through all the Groovy and non-Ruby Grape tags, and retagged the appropriate ones as [groovy-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-grape).  Therefore, the [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) tag should now consist solely of Ruby Grape tags.

I therefore request that a moderator please rename the [grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) tag to [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape).  Additionally, the existing [grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api) tag should be made a synonym of the new [ruby-grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-grape) tag.